# How to redirect to the original url after login in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, redirect

If i open a url required login to access, after the login was done i wish to be redirected to the original url. How can i achieve this in Tornado? I searched in Google but nothing useful found. I used the following code but it does not work.

```
def LoginHandler(RequestHandler):
    if not self.current_user:
        self.render("login.html")
    else:
        self.redirect(self.request.headers["Referer"])
```

I used the Google developer tool and find that when the url is redirected to login page the 'Referer' field does not exist in the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`@web.authenticated`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.authenticated) to require login on your handlers, it will redirect the user to the login page with the current url in the `next` parameter.

For example, if you request for `/protected/page`, and if you're not logged in, you'll be redirected to the login page with this url - `/login?next=/protected/page`.

In your login handler check for the `next` parameter and redirect.

```
self.redirect(self.get_query_argument('next', '/default/url/if/next/is/empty'))
```

Comment: Thanks for for your response. I have not use the @web.authenticated decorator but implement my own access control layer. But i finally achieve this inspired by your answer.

Comment: I add a new 'next' argument to the login uri whose value is the currently request one in the redirect when a user is not logged, and write this argument to the login page when rendering and when the user is logging i send this argument along with the user password info and finally i can do the redirect using this extra argument.